# Configuration for mobile-friendly Airbnb's react-dates library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I've been exploring the [Airbnb's react-dates library](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) and am having a difficult time trying to wrap my thoughts around how to trigger it's mobile responsiveness API. Currently, I have the 'minimum required' code to have a functioning calendar, however, I do not think it's mobile-friendly off the shelf.

Another solution that I may attempt, is manually implementing media queries in the css to trigger a mobile-friendly layout, but this solution seems wrong and/or "over-engineered".

Please note that I am looking for guidance towards proper configuration for a mobile-friendly react-dates calendar and not a copy/paste style solution.

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issuse found in their github page

https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/1242
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/262

**Neither helped me** so I ended up with my own solution.

```
 <DateRangePicker
          readOnly
          verticalHeight={370}
          orientation="vertical"
          numberOfMonths={1}
...
...
/>
```